# Como transferir dados de tabelas para o python?

Tags: python, array, linux

Olá, Tenho uma tabela com muitos dados, muitos dados mesmo de Astrofísica, são tabelas com aproximadamente 20 colunas e mais de 1000 linhas. Preciso enviar essa tabela com esses dados (contidos nas colunas e linhas) para o python 2.7 no meu linux mas não consigo fazer isso. Poderiam me ajudar por gentileza?

Comment: A tua pergunta está um pouco vaga, sem objetividade. Já pensou em usar o [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) para isso? Veja esse *"quickstart"*: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html

Comment: Como assim enviar para o python?

Comment: Em que formato está essa tabela?

Answer (score 0):

Se você se refere a passar os dados como parâmetros para seu script Python, na linha de comando, eu sugeriria duas alternativas:

1. Passar como o caminho para um arquivo: `python meuscript.py /caminho/para/tabela.txt`
2. Passar como o input (stdin): `python meyscript.py < /caminho/para/tabela.txt`

A segunda alternativa é mais flexível pois também permitirá usos como: `python gerar-tabela.py param1 param2 | python meuscript.py`

Answer (score 0):

Como você não mencionou file format irei assumir xlsx.

Fazendo um pseudo-code em EAFP imagino que você possa fazer algo assim (como você não mencionou, imagino que não esteja usando nenhuma biblioteca de análise de dados como http://pandas.pydata.org/ por exemplo) - como seus dados são científicos é provável que uma simples leitura e iteração de tabelas não seja suficiente, todavia:

```
import xlrd

def open_file(caminho_de_arquivo):
    """
    Definição da função que irá ler e criar no seu runtime a tabela equivalente
    ao arquivo
    """
livro = xlrd.open_workbook(caminho_de_arquivo)

# exibir no console o número de planilhas
print livro.nsheets

# exibir o nome das planilhas
print livro.sheet_names()

# obter a primeira planilha, assinalando-a a uma variável local
primeira_planilha = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# exibir a primeira coluna da primeira planilha
print primeira_planilha.row_values(0)

# obter e exibir uma célula da primeira planilha
cell = primeira_planilha.cell(0,0)
print cell
print cell.value

# ler um slice de linha
print primeira_planilha.row_slice(rowx=0,
                            start_colx=0,
                            end_colx=2)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "caminho.xls"
    open_file(path)with open('filepath.xlsx', 'r') as importer:
```

A partir disto você pode iterar sobre a planilha como quiser de forma simples:

```
cells = primeira_planilha.row_slice(rowx=0,
                              start_colx=0,
                              end_colx=2)
for cell in cells:
    print cell.value
```

Tutorial retirado e traduzido do post http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/04/30/reading-excel-spreadsheets-with-python-and-xlrd/